# ROS Repository apt-get tab completion

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully imported the ROS Ubuntu repositories for my platform, but the bash tab-completion for the ROS packages is not present.

Tab-completion works for other packages in the Ubuntu repositories, and I can apt-get install any of the ROS packages, they just don't tab complete.

Is there any way to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9188/ros-repository-apt-get-tab-completion/) by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm still not entirely sure what the problem is, but running the command:

```
source /etc/bash_completion
```

Seems to have fixed the problem.

I have also added it to my ~/.bash_profile file so that it will be fixed on all shells.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-24**:
@Tully Foote, it does seem like an odd problem.  It has worked with previous combinations of ROS and Ubuntu, but for some reason it didn't work this time around.  The only reason that I've asked is that I've seen the behavior on 3 computers now.  It may possibly be a Ubuntu release problem.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-02-24**:
This is odd, but at least it's working.  Usually it just works like the other things in the repo.